# Two lists same container same store

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I got this class where I'm trying to show some data from the same store in the same container. I did it this way because I want to have two rows each on a separate line and I was not having 
too much control over them. Here's the class:

```
Ext.define('Clue.view.ListQuestions', {
extend: 'Ext.Container',
requires: ['Ext.dataview.List'],
xtype: 'listquestions',


config: {
    id: 'listquestions',
    items: [{
         xtype: 'list',
         id: 'questionLi1',
         baseCls: 'questionLi1',
         flex: 1,
         store: {
             xtype: 'levelstore',
             filters: [{
                 filterFn: function(item) {
                     return item.data.levelId < 2 && item.data.questionId < 6;
                 }
             }]
         },
         itemTpl: '<div>{questionId}</div>'
     },{
        xtype: 'list',
        id: 'questionLi2',
        baseCls: 'questionLi2',

        flex: 1,
        store: {
            xtype: 'levelstore',
            filters: [{
                filterFn: function(item) {
                    return item.data.levelId < 2 && item.data.questionId > 5;
                }
            }]
        },
        itemTpl: '<div>{questionId}</div>'
    }]
}
 })
```

If I remove the second list, first list is showing, otherwise the first list is not showing. What I'm doing wrong ?
here's the store:

```
Ext.define('Clue.store.LQuestions', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
xtype: 'levelstore',
requires: ['Ext.data.proxy.LocalStorage'],

config: {
    model: 'Clue.model.LQuestions',
    storeId: 'levelStore',
    sorters: [{
        property: 'levelId',
        direction: 'ASC'
    }],
    proxy: {
        type: 'localstorage',
        id:   'levelstorage'
    }
}
})
```

**other details**

I added some css on the questionLi1 and questionLi2 and their items. 3px red border. the lists are taking space but in the first list elements are not there ( not even in html ) second list is rendered fine. if I put a console.log() in the first filterFn function nothing shows up.. so I was thinking that maybe I overwrite something...

this is what I get

[image: both lists active]

and if I do:

```
... 
flex: 1,
 /*store: {
      xtype: 'levelstore',
      filters: [{
          filterFn: function(item) {
               return item.data.levelId < 2 && item.data.questionId > 5;
          }
      }]
        },*/
 itemTpl: '<div>{questionId}</div>'
...
```

on the second list I get
[image]

Comment: Add layout: 'vbox' to your container

Comment: I think a screenshot would be good.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a flex config to a component only works if you specify a vbox of hbox layout to its parent like so

```
    Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
        fullscreen: true,
        layout: 'vbox',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'list',
            itemTpl: '{title}',
            flex: 1,
            data: [
                { title: 'List 1: Item 1' },
                { title: 'List 1: Item 2' },
                { title: 'List 1: Item 3' },
                { title: 'List 1: Item 4' }
            ]
        }, {
            xtype: 'list',
            itemTpl: '{title}',
            flex: 1,
            data: [
                { title: 'List 2: Item 1' },
                { title: 'List 2: Item 2' },
                { title: 'List 2: Item 3' },
                { title: 'List 2: Item 4' }
            ]
        }]
    });
```

[Sencha Fiddle](http://www.senchafiddle.com/#JvAfe)

Comment: well that's not the case. anyway you are right with the layout thing. I'll edit my question to explain a little more.